# Heyzap integration 3rd party sdks missing permissions

Tags: adcolony, applovin, heyzap

I am trying to integrate ads in my android app through Heyzap. However, when i open the heyzap mediation suite, some of the third party sdks are marked with "missing permissions". these are AdColony, AppLovin, ChartBoost and Vungle. They all have "Sdk detected", "all activities found" and "credentials found" marked with green. the other sdks have "all permissions found". The thing is that when the app is trying to fetch an add it crashes.
What I would like to know if these crashes have anything to do with the sdks with missing permissions and if yes, how can i solve this problem?

I read  "how to"s for each sdk and put all the mentioned permissions in my manifest but still nothing. 
Can you, please, help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the same Missing Permissions error for Vungle, Applovin, Chartboost and AdColony.

For me **removing  android:maxSdkVersion="18" from the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the Vungle manifest** made the issue disappear for all four networks. By Vungle manifest I mean the AndroidManifest file in Plugins/Android/Vungle_lib

As per [Google specification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element) the permission is not needed any more for API level 19 and above so I guess that's why Vungle adds the parameter. But somehow the Heyzap Mediation Suite keeps telling us that we are missing permissions. My guess is that there's something wrong with the Heyzap Mediation Suite since ad serving works even with the Missing Permissions warning.

Comment: Yes, it was a Heyzap Mediation thing, nothing to do with the individual sdks. Thank you!